# Looping with XPath in PHP

Tags: php, loops, dom, xpath

I have this html table:

```
<tbody>
   <tr class="r1">

      <td class="l rbrd">
         <img class="spr2 sport sp1" align="absmiddle" src="/s.gif">
      </td>

      <td class="l rbrd">19/4 18:30</td>

      <td class="l rbrd">
         <a title="CHELSEA FC - SUNDERLAND" href="/chelsea-fc-vs-sunderland/e/4509648/" target="_blank">CHELSEA FC - SUNDERLAND</a>
      </td>

      <td class="c w40">
         <span class="o">1,21</span>
         <span class="p">91,8%</span>
      </td>

   </tr>
```

There are more than one hundred <"tr"> structured at the same way, which contain lots of <"td">. How can i loop with xpath to store all data in a database?

This is my php code, but i can not go on.. help!

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init('http://www.oxybet.ro/pariu/external/betfair-volumes.htm');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/8.0.552.224 Safari/534.10');
$html = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

if (!$html) {
    die("something's wrong!");
}

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$scores = array();

$tableRows = $xpath->query('//div//div//div[2]//div/div//table');

foreach ($tableRows->tr as $row) {

   $td = $xpath->query('td', $row);
    // we'll store information about each match in this array
    $match = array();
...
```

}

Final result:

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 18:30 19/4
            [teams] => CHELSEA FC - SUNDERLAND
            [1] => 1,21
            [1 volumes] => 91,8%

        )
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse HTML Table with DOM and XPath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23169218/parse-html-table-with-dom-and-xpath)

Comment: Don't post duplicates. This just leads to people doing double effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following approach.

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.oxybet.ro/pariu/external/betfair-volumes.htm';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTML($response);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($document);
$expression = '/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr';
$rows = $xpath->query($expression);

$results = array();

foreach ($rows as $row) {
  $result = array();

  $expression = './td[2]';
  $result['date'] = $xpath->query($expression, $row)->item(0)->nodeValue;

  $expression = './td[3]/a';
  $result['teams'] = $xpath->query($expression, $row)->item(0)->nodeValue;

  $expression = './td[4]/span';
  $result['1'] = $xpath->query($expression, $row)->item(0)->nodeValue;

  $expression = './td[4]/span[2]';
  $result['1 volumes'] = $xpath->query($expression, $row)->item(0)->nodeValue;

  array_push($results, $result);
}

var_dump($results);
```